# Python Map List of Strings to Integer List

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list

```
l = ['michael','michael','alice','carter']
```

I want to map it to the following:

```
k = [1,1,2,3]
```

Where michael corresponds to 1, alice corresponds to 2 etc. Is there a function in Python to do this easily?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord), which gives the unicode number for a given character:

```
>>> letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
>>> [ord(x) for x in letters]
[97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103]
```

So you could do `ord(x)-96` to convert `a-z` to `1-26` (careful about upper case, etc).

```
l = ['a','b','a','c']
k = [ord(x)-96 for x in l] # [1,2,1,3]
```

Again, careful about upper case and non-alphabet characters.

Comment: This only works for a list of characters, not for a list of strings as in the OP's question.

Comment: Note that the original question only had a list of characters. The edit to the question was made after this answer was given and accepted!

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that. In that case, I wish the OP had asked the 'string' question as a separate question. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

How about using Pandas?

```py
import pandas as pd
l = ['michael','michael','alice','carter']
pd.Series(l).astype('category').cat.codes.values
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to answer the edited question, i.e., to map the list of strings to unique integers, one has to first find the unique strings and then do 1-1 mapping of the strings to integers in the original list of strings. For example,

```
s = ['michael','michael','alice','carter']
```

then unique strings are `{'michael','alice','carter'}`. Now, convert these strings to integers by 1-1 mapping like `{'michael','alice','carter'} =[1,2,3]` using dictionary `{'michael':1,'alice':2,'carter':3}`. In the third step, loop through the original list of strings; search the string in the dictionary for the corresponding integer and replace the string by that integer.

```
s=['michael','michael','alice','carter']

mydict={}
i = 0
for item in s:
    if(i>0 and item in mydict):
        continue
    else:    
       i = i+1
       mydict[item] = i

k=[]
for item in s:
    k.append(mydict[item])
```

Output:

```
k=[1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

To map list of integers to list of strings I would use a dictionary, for example:

```
> name_number = {'michael':1, 'michael':1, 'alice':2, 'carter':3}
> print len(name_number)
  3
> print name_number['alice']
  2
```

Note that `len(name_number)` is `3`, because duplicate keys are not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading you correctly, you want to take a list of characters and convert them to integers, with a being 1, b being 2, etc.

```
l = ['a','b','a','c']
k = [ord(x.upper()) - 64 for x in l]
```

Threw the `upper()` in there so it doesn't matter whether they're upper case or lower.

Answer (score 1):

The function is [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html)

E.g:

```
>>> l = ['a','b','a','c']
>>> k = [1,2,1,3]¨
>>> zip(l,k)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 1), ('c', 3)]
```

If you want to use the items of `l` as index, you want an dictionary:

```
>>> d = dict(zip(l,k))
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> d['a']
1
>>> d['c']
3
>>>
```

Comment: zip does not check for correspondence, if k is reversed, the results will be different.

Answer (score 0):

can do it pretty easy without a function :

```
j - list()    
for i in range (len(l)) : 
   j.append((l[i],k[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear if you want to generate k based on l or both l and k are given.

If you are looking to create k based on l, @mathematical.coffee's answer should do.

If you want a map from items in l to k, obviously, your items in `l` should be unique.

See if this is what you were looking for

```
dict((l[index], k[index]) for index in range(len(l)))
```

Or else, if you are looking for tuples:

```
[(l[index], k[index]) for index in range(len(l))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order of the assigned ids, this works:

```
# create unique list of  names
unique_l = set(l)

# create mappings from names to id
name2id = {name: idx+1 for idx, name in enumerate(unique_l)}

# map initial list of names to ids
k = [name2id[name] for name in l]
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind missing the mapping restriction, probably this is another good may to do it.

```
import numpy as np
names, tags = np.unique(l, return_inverse=True)

print(names)  # ['alice' 'carter' 'michael']
print(tags)   # [2, 2, 0, 1]
```

Hope this can help in the future.