# Mapping List of Strings to floating numbers - Python

Tags: python, string, list, floating-point

I need to map country list in to floating number list.

```
country_list = ['China','India','Japan',...etc]
```

Mapping should be like following. (Just an example).

```
China  0.1
India  0.2
Japan  0.3
....   ...
....   1.0
....   1.1
....   ...
....   2.0
```

What is the most quick way doing this with Python.

Related Questions : [Python Map List of Strings to Integer List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206609/python-map-list-of-strings-to-integer-list)

Comment: Wait, what? You suspect that there is a duplicate to your question, and you post it anyway? Why? :|

Comment: Mapping to what? where are those numebrs? in a list with the same indexes? If that is yes, use zip, someone mentioned that in the response you linked to.

Comment: @BartoszKP: That is different from what I need, but it addresses a similar question, That is why I indicated it.

Comment: @Raul Guiu : I need to map it to floating points starting 0.1 to ..n?

Comment: @BartoszKP: to be fair, the "possible duplicate" was edited to match this question pretty well, but the original question that was actually answered has nothing to do with this and the edit completely invalidated all of the answers.

Comment: What if there are duplicates?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage All right, I understand. Perhaps use the word "related" next time then :)

Comment: @Jayanth Koushik : No duplicates for country list..Why down votes :(

Comment: You probably shouldn't have said 'Possible duplicate'. Anyways I haven't downvoted. Downvoters should check the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the floats, zip the two lists.

```
>>> country_list = ['China', 'India', 'Japan']
>>> numbers = list(x/10.0 for x in range(1, len(country_list)+1))
>>> zip(country_list, numbers)
[('China', 0.1), ('India', 0.2), ('Japan', 0.3)]

>>> print "\n".join("{} {}".format(x, y) for x, y in _)
China 0.1
India 0.2
Japan 0.3
```

EDIT: replaced the `float(x)*0.1` to a division.