# Mapping two arrays containing strings to the same integer values

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, integer

I have 2 arrays like:

```
['16.37.235.200','17.37.235.200','16.37.235.200', '18.37.235.200']
['17.37.235.200','17.37.235.200','16.37.235.200', '17.37.235.200']
```

And I want to map (injective) every IP address to an integer value.
Like for that instance above, eg.:

```
[0,1,0,3]
[1,1,0,1]
```

Is their an existing function (of NumPy or anything else) for that?

Comment: Existing functionality in what? Are you looking specifically at Python since you mentioned numpy?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, forgot to mention its in python.

Comment: could you elaborate more for the mapping process. for eg: if ip :16.37.235.200 is mapped to 0 , what is the ip corresponding to digit 2

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found this solution for seperate mapping of the lists
[Python Map List of Strings to Integer List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206609/python-map-list-of-strings-to-integer-list)

Works like i want for seperated mapping of the 2 lists.